# How to stop the Swiffy zoom-in effect

Tags: google-swiffy

I am using swiffy to use an animation in my webpage but the problem that its size is not static, when the page loads the animation is evolving in size from small to big.

Here is an example - http://neweratravels.in/akriti/rotate-testing.html

I want to make the animation stop expanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the size for the swiffycontainer div at "width: 407; height:400;". You need to say those are pixels, otherwise they don't take effect and the swiffy canvas will fill the screen. Change it to "width: 407px; height:400px;" and it works.
[image]